# mongoose static method returns a bluebird promise

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I am creating a mongoose static method 'load' so that my main controller function can use it (for chainning and error handling).

```
UserSchema.load('54ae92dd8b8eef540eb3a66d')
.then(....)
.catch(....);
```

The thing is the id is something wrong so I need to catch this error.  and I am thinking it is better to do this in the model layer.

When I do the following the controller can catch this error.

```
UserSchema.statics.load = function(id) {

    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        return Promise.resolve().then(function() {
            throw new Error('not a mongoose id');
        }); ------------( * )
    }

    return Promise.cast(this.findOne({
        _id: id
    }).exec());
};
```

But if I only do the following the error is not successfully thrown into the controller .catch function.

```
AchievementSchema.statics.load = function(id) {
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        throw new Error('not a mongoose id');
    }
    return Promise.cast(this.findOne({
        _id: id
    }).exec());
};
```

so my question is am I doing this correctly?  If so is there easier ways to write the (*) statement?  What I am doing seems ugly.. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a shorthand called `Promise.reject`.

Your code in:

```
if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    return Promise.resolve().then(function() {
        throw new Error('not a mongoose id');
    }); ------------( * )
}
```

Can be written as:

```
return Promise.reject(new Error("Not a mongoose id");
```

You can do even better though, `Promise.method` exists to ensure anything that might return a promise *will* return a promise:

```
UserSchema.statics.load = Promise.method(function(id) {

    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        throw new Error('not a mongoose id: ' + id);
    }
    return this.findOne({ _id: id }).exec());
});
```

This will both case the `findOne` result to a Bluebird trusted promise and convert the `throw` to a rejection for you. You might want to consider throwing a subclass of `Promise.OperationalError` rather than `Error` though.

As an unrelated tip `Promise.cast` was deprecated in favor of `Promise.resolve` over a year ago.

Comment: would the promises inside `Promise.method` have race conditions if I don't cast all of the promises to bluebird promise?